# Foreach loop with images

Tags: c#, winapp

I have an 80 PNG image sequence in which I am trying to create an animation for my windows app. The file path is Assets/Star/ and I am trying to figure out how I would make a foreach loop for each image in the folder, so it would set the image object as Image1 then after a certain amount of ticks with the timer it would change it to Image2 and so on, here is what I have so far:

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      if(LevelUp == true)
        {
            string ImagePath = "Assets/Star/";
            foreach (Image item in ImagePath)
            {

            }
        }
   }
```

However I dont think im approaching it correctly, does anyone know how i should approach this?

Comment: Where is your timer?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a simple GIF instead of 80 different PNGs?

Comment: Maybe he wants quality colors..

Comment: You need a Timer and need to code its Tick event.. The button will do nothing but start the Timer (and maybe prepare an ImageList)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault PNG would be much preferred considering it's quality is brill

Answer (score 2):

Just `await Task.Delay` to asynchronously wait for a set span of time:

```
private async void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (LevelUp)
    {
        string imagePath = "Assets/Star/";
        foreach (Image image in GetImages(imagePath))
        {
            ShowImage(image);
            await Task.Delay(timeToWait);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of setting a time span?

Comment: @JermainDefo Yes, of course there is.  `timeToWait` in this example is a variable specifying the amount of time to wait.  Set it to whatever you want.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think it would be that easy! So the await Task.Delay is the timer itself? In other words, this will be the solution?

Comment: @JermainDefo `Task.Delay` uses a timer internally to create a `Task` that  will be completed after the specified delay.  You don't need to interact with that timer directly.

Comment: The GetImages isn't recognised. I have an error stating "The name GetImages does not exist in the current context" do you have any idea why?

Comment: @JermainDefo Because you haven't written it yet.  You'll need to write the method to get all of the images in a given path.

Comment: Since the images are named like Image1, Image2, Image3 etc.. Would it not be possible to declare the file path with the image such as "Assets/Images/Image" && number (where the number variable is added by a 1 everytime it comes across a photo) so if 3 was stored in number it would come out as "Assets/Images/Image3", if this is possible to do wouldnt it be better so its in a chronological order?